# Timespan data type C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have a timespan value which is **difference** of two Datetime values. It is like this :

```
myvalue = {41870.01:44:22.8365404}
```

I have also a string which represents another timespan value and it is like this :

```
ttime= "23:55" // which means 23 minutes and 55 seconds
```

I want to check if myvalue is smaller than ttime. Here is my attempt:

```
if(myvalue < Timespan.Parse(ttime))
//do this
else
//do that
```

Is my approach correct enough? Do I need to do something else? Thanks.

Comment: _"Is my approach correct enough?"_ Do you have any specific concerns?

Comment: It would be much faster if you tested it yourself with different values covering two branches of if statement. Write some unit tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem i can see is that `TimeSpan.Parse` is limited to 24 hours. So you would need this workaround:

```
string ttime = "48:23:55"; // 48 hours
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(ttime.Split(':')[0]),    // hours
                           int.Parse(ttime.Split(':')[1]),    // minutes
                           int.Parse(ttime.Split(':')[2]));   // seconds
```

Apart from that it's absolutely fine to compare two timespan in this way.

If it  can contain two or three parts(with or without hours), this should be safer:

```
string[] tokens = ttime.Split(':');
// support only two or three tokens:
if (tokens.Length < 2 || tokens.Length > 3)
    throw new NotSupportedException("Timespan could not be parsed successfully: " + ttime);
TimeSpan ts;
if(tokens.Length == 3)
    ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(tokens[0]), int.Parse(tokens[1]),int.Parse(tokens[2]));
else
    ts = new TimeSpan(0, int.Parse(tokens[0]), int.Parse(tokens[1]));
```

---

For what it's worth, here is a method which is written from scratch which parses a string to `TimeSpan` by allowing two or three tokens(hh,mm,ss or mm,ss) and also supports weird formats like `100:100:100` (100 hours + 100 minutes + 100 seconds):

```
public static TimeSpan SaferTimeSpanParse(string input, char delimiter = ':')
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input must not be null or empty", "input");
    string[] tokens = input.Split(delimiter);
    if (tokens.Length < 2 || tokens.Length > 3)
        throw new NotSupportedException("Timespan could not be parsed successfully: " + input);
    int i;
    if (!tokens.All(t => int.TryParse(t, out i) && i >= 0))
        throw new ArgumentException("All token must contain a positive integer", "input");

    int[] all = tokens.Select(t => int.Parse(t)).ToArray();
    int hoursFinal = 0, minutesFinal = 0, secondsFinal = 0;

    int seconds = all.Last();
    secondsFinal = seconds % 60;
    minutesFinal = seconds / 60;

    int minutes = (all.Length == 3 ? all[1] : all[0]) + minutesFinal; // add current minutes which might already be increased through seconds
    minutesFinal = minutes % 60;
    hoursFinal = minutes / 60;

    hoursFinal = all.Length == 3 ? all[0] + hoursFinal : hoursFinal; // add current hours which might already be increased through minutes

    return new TimeSpan(hoursFinal, minutesFinal, secondsFinal);
}
```

tested with your string, my string and a weird one:

```
Console.WriteLine(SaferTimeSpanParse("23:55"));
Console.WriteLine(SaferTimeSpanParse("48:23:55"));
Console.WriteLine(SaferTimeSpanParse("100:100:100"));
```

Output:

```
00:23:55
2.00:23:55
4.05:41:40
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it is 48 minutes and 33 seconds, not hours and minutes.

Comment: How about using custom format `TimeSpan.ParseExact(ttime, @"mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: has the same problem with hours exceeding 23 (`OverflowException`).

Comment: Ou, I see, sorry about that. The only consideration I saw is format difference: OP had `"23:55"` while in your answer it is `"48:23:55"`. In first case he'll get `IndexOutOfRangeException`, hope OP will figure this out.